# xpath to find the node with maximum attributes

Tags: xpath

I have an xml structure like this.

```
    <pages>
        <page a="1">111</page>
        <page a="1" b="2">222</page>
        <page a="1">333</page>
        <page a="1" b="2" c="3" d="4">444</page>
        <page a="1" b="2">555</page>
        <page a="1">666</page>
    </pages>
```

Xpath should return the value 444 since that node has got the maximum number of attributes. How can we do this? Please help.

Comment: i need this for Orbeon Xforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xpath-2-0-support Orbeon supports XPath 2.0 so you can do stuff like `/pages/page[count(@*) eq max(/pages/page/count(@*))]`.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question has [already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019837/find-the-maximum-child-count-with-xpath-1-0) and the conclusion is that it isn't really feasible yet. There doesn't seem to be a max() function in the current XPath specifications, so I think you'll have to apply some more complex code to get your answer... :)